# Liquibase/SQLite syntax error

Tags: sqlite, liquibase

So I have a sqlite database. My game (C#) is able to open it and run it quite nicely. However, for maintainability and potential conflict reasons, I would like a more manageable format. Our project manager suggested Liquibase. I'm not sure if it's just out of date or what, but it will NOT convert for me, and I'm not sure why. Here's what we got:

running on windows 8.1

liquibase version 3.3.0 (http://www.liquibase.org/download/index.html)

sqlite database made using sqlite manager demo version 4.3.5 (http://www.sqlabs.com/sqlitemanager.php)

java version 8 update 25

sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7 (https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)

The command I enter is...

```
liquibase --classpath=sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC\
--url="jdbc:sqlite:GameData.sqlite" --changeLogFile=gamedb-canges.xml\
--username=username --password=password generateChangeLog
```

and the error I get is...

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] 
SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
```

Comment: Can't you find out what SQL command it tried to execute?

Comment: My experience with Liquibase is very good and the support for the main stream DBs (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server) is really good. I guess it just hasn't been tested properly with SQLite (SQLite isn't really that common in the Java world, there are better embedded alternatives there).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try removing the quotes around the URL. You can also include --logLevel=debug on the command line to get better diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

"SQL error or missing database" is [an error message](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) that comes from the SQLite db.

Try to add a full path to the sqlite db like:

```
--url="jdbc:sqlite:C:\myPath\GameData.sqlite"
```